# BEM with SASS and :hover

Tags: css, sass, bem

What's the proper way of declaring active/focus/hover states using BEM with SASS? For example, I have this structure:

```
<div class="card">
    <img class="card__image" src="..." alt="">
    <div class="card__overlay">
        <div class="card__title"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the SCSS:

```
.card {
   &__image {
   }

   &__overlay {
   }

   &__title {
   }
}
```

And I want to modify the elements when hovering on the block.
This doesn't work:

```
.card {
   &__overlay {
       display: none;
   }

   &:hover {
       &__overlay {
           display: block;
       }
   }
}
```

And having to write the whole `.project__image` just for this one instance seems wrong.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: The problem here is what, exactly?  If you look at the compiled results, the answer seems pretty obvious.  Try running the results through the validator if you still don't understand what's wrong with the CSS.

Comment: It works. Check [this](http://sassmeister.com/gist/a5bb2d884cb0c2d12f9e).

Comment: It's the second code section that doesn't work, not the first. The one with the hover state.

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not explain what the problem is.  http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't work because it compiles to `.card:hover__overlay` instead of the desired `.card:hover .card__overlay`.

Answer (score 54):

You can achieve the desired result using the [Sass ampersand selector](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand), without using variables or interpolation.

> Referencing parent selectors by using the ampersand (&) can be a
>   powerful tool, if used right. There are simple uses of this feature as
>   well as some very complex uses of this feature.

For example:

```
.card { 

    &__overlay {
        display:none;
    }

    &:hover & {
        &__overlay  {
            display: block;
        }   
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
.card__overlay {
    display: none;
}

.card:hover .card__overlay {
    display: block;
}
```

This code uses fewer language constructs (e.g. no use of variables or interpolation) and so is arguably a cleaner implementation.

Comment: Don't know why I never thought of this, it's genius. But what if you need to apply styles to card:hover as well?

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant!

Comment: This doesn't work if its nested inside any other parent (it becomes .parent .card .parent .card__overlay)

Answer (score 24):

Read more about interpolation:
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_

SCSS:

```
.card {
    $root: &;

    &__overlay {
        display: none;

        #{$root}:hover & {
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```

RESULT:

```
.card__overlay {
  display: none;
}

.card:hover .card__overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

PS. It is similar to @alireza safian post, but with this way you don't need to duplicate class name. Variable `$root` do it for you :)

Comment: Unfortunately Gonzales PE version: 3.0.0-28 doesn't seems to like that syntax :S

Comment: This feels like an anti-pattern

Answer (score 4):

Alternative way:

**Use variable instead of ampersand** for third level.

[Link](http://sassmeister.com/gist/0337de038a42cd51c529)

SASS:

```
$className: card;
.card {
   &__overlay {
       display: none;
   }

   &:hover {

       .#{$className}__overlay {
           display: block;
       }
   }
}
```

CSS:

```
.card__overlay {
  display: none;
}

.card:hover .card__overlay {
  display: block;
}
```