# Element:hover doesn't affect child

Tags: sass

I'm coding a website for my learning path and I got following issue:
When I Hover `&__item`, the animation property doesn't appears in style of `&__selection`...

**sass code:**

```css
&__item {
  /*...*/

  __selection{
    /*...*/
  }

  &:hover &__selection {
    animation: animSelect 800ms ease-in-out 0ms 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the BEM naming convention, to target the `__selection` class there are a couple of ways you can do it, this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021910/bem-with-sass-and-hover) also covers this issue very well, for now these are my guess

```
&__item {
  /*...*/

  __selection{
    /*...*/
  }

  &:hover __selection { //more of a normal css solution

    animation: animSelect 800ms ease-in-out 0ms 1;

  }
}
```

or

```
.item{ 

    &__selection {
         /*...*/
    }

    &:hover & {
        &__selection  {
             /*...*/
        }   
    }
}
```